# Scanning on the HP PSC 1401 without a cartridge installed

Tags: troubleshooting, printer, scanner

Is it possible to scan documents using the HP PSC 1401 combination printer/scanner if there is no printer cartridge installed? When I turn it on (without a cartridge) the "no cartridge" light blinks and I am unable to scan.